# Como usar componentes exportados de outros módulos no Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routes

Estou começando a utilizar o Angular 2 e estou tendo problemas para acessar um componente existente em um módulo que criei.

Ao abrir a aplicação, rota `root` deve ser direcionada para o modulo **`IndexModule`** onde seu `boostrap` é feito no componente geral do mesmo **`IndexComponent`**, assim:

**IndexModule.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { IndexComponent } from './index.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [IndexComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [IndexComponent],
  providers: [],
  boostrap: [IndexComponent]
})

export class IndexModule {}
```

E este **`IndexModule`** fica vinculado ao módulo raiz da aplicação **`AppModule`** assim:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { IndexModule } from './index/index.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, IndexModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Meu problema é que, mesmo olhando em inúmeros locais na internet, de como devo trabalhar com o sistema de rotas (como [aqui](https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli), [aqui](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)...) só consegui chegar à solução que eu teria que modificar meu **`AppModule`** inserindo a inicial no mesmo e, mesmo vinculando o módulo **`IndexModule`** ao módulo raiz, ainda teria que forçar o roteamento para o componente **`IndexComponent`**, assim:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IndexModule } from './index/index.module';
import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const router = [{
  path: '',
  component: IndexComponent
}]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(router),

    IndexModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Como posso acessar meu componente **`IndexComponent`** existente dentro do módulo já importado para o módulo raiz para definir sua rota? É possível fazer com que no **`AppModule`** eu possa dizer para que ele simplesmente busque possíveis rotas existentes dentro do **`IndexModule`**?

**EDIT**

Pode-se dizer que o que não aceito é que eu tenha que importar o **`IndexModule`** para anexar ao **`AppModule`** e, mesmo assim ainda tenho que importar o **`IndexComponent`** (mesmo já estando dentro do **`IndexModule`**). Eu sei que não preciso é necessário importar o **`IndexModule`** mas se caso eu utilizar mais de um recurso desse módulo, seria mais "otimizado" a importação somente do módule e trabalhar com algo assim

```
IndexModule.<MeuComponenteOuQualquerOutraCoisa> // Ex: IndexModule.IndexComponent
```

Se eu conseguisse alguma maneira de utilizar o **`IndexComponent`** sem precisar declará-lo (que entendo que uma dupla referência) já seria satisfatório para meu código.

> A intenção desse post não é precisamente manipular as rotas em questão mas, sim trabalhar com os componentes existentes dentro de outro módulo (com apenas o import desse módulo).

Basicamente, não quero ter que fazer isso:

```
//importação em redundância porque 'IndexComponent' é exportado no 'IndexModule'
import { IndexModule } from './index/index.module';
import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';
```

Comment: Se seu código não for muito grande, poderia subir no github, eu uso modulos e rotas vindas de modulos em meu projeto e basta importar o outro módulo e usar o componente. Não consegui ver onde está errado no seu com o o código que você apresentou.

Comment: O que eu entendo como errado é que eu tenha que definir as rotas da página Index no módulo ´AppModule` sendo que a Index é seu submódulo. E se eu não fizer isso, sou obrigado a Inserir a tag do component Index...

Comment: No angular se usa o exports de um modulo para expor os components dele que vc quiser.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisar criar um modulo intermediário, porque o app.module que teve o index.module importado não consegue visualizar os componentes exportados por index.module. Para que o app.module consiga visualizar é necessário ter um modulo transitivo.

**Tente fazer desta forma:**

**1.** Crie um novo modulo: transtive.module.ts

**2.** Este novo modulo vai exportar o index.module

**3.** Após fazer isso tire o index.module e index.component do app.module

**4.** Por fim importe o transitive.module no app.module.

Desta forma você conseguirá visualizar na aplicação toda o index.component.

Este problema se deve a seguinte regra de angular: **Os seletores aplicáveis ​​durante a compilação de um modelo de componente são determinados pelo módulo que declara esse componente e o fechamento transitivo das exportações das importações desse módulo.**